# Dealing with commas and quote in a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, xls

I have searched the internet about the comma issues about csv document.But my trouble is about dealing with the value containing not only comma but also quote.
like `String value = "FName,\"FName2,FName3";` 
I want to display the string **FName,"FName2,FName3**  in the csv document.Though i tried a couple of approaches,but failed.
When the string contains comma,I can use double quote to surround it like code below.

```
outBuff.append("\\").append(cellData).append("\\").append(",");
```

But when the string contains "" and ,
How can i deal with this issue?

I can only use the pulest java,and can not use the third part library.
Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples -- for entries that contain a comma, surround with quotes. Escape quotes with two double-quote characters.

Comment: have tried quotes,but not work

Comment: Show what you actually tried. Or to figure it out for yourself put some data in a spreadsheet (excel, openoffice calc) and export to csv. Then open the csv with a text file and you can see what works.

Comment: Is this homework? Because a pro would use a library to do this (I do), why waste time on such mundane tasks, and risk not handling corner cases, when someone has already solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using os specialized CSV parser, like one from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)

It will handle most of corner cases for you

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuffer sbStudentData = new StringBuffer();    

sbStudentData.append(",\"").append(LastName).append(",\"").append(FirstName)
```

it will work fine like Last name,First name.

Answer (score 0):

try enclosing your double quote with two double qoutes:
 `String value = "FName,\"\"\"FName2,FName3";`

Comment: I tried like this,cellData.replace("\"", "\"\""),but it not works.